# Boot up black screen

Tags: display

During boot up I get for a fraction of a second a black screen with three lines of errors. Otherwise the system works perfectly, boots ok and operates very fast. Should I bother about those lines? Is there a way to stop the screen and read what the info is? Thanks for a kind suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Execute on terminal `dmesg | grep error`. That's probably going to show those errors you see at boot. You can just use `dmesg` to see all the output and search manually.

If your errors are like:

```
usb 1-1.4: string descriptor 0 read error: -22
```

Then it should be fine, otherwise you can create a new question or ask me in the comments :)

Comment: Many thanks I much obliged for offer to help out. I am pasting the result - just errors off dmesg: CPI Error: [^^^GFX0.AFN4] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/psargs-359)
[    5.675871] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC0.SACL] (Node ffff8aac960ca370), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/psparse-543)
[    5.675879] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC0._Q09] (Node ffff8aac960ca528), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/psparse-543)
[    5.84402

Comment: Hmm im not really sure but it seems some driver isn't correctly configured. If you don't miss anything and your computer works let it be that way. otherwise you better ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Everything works fine, I will live with it. If not broken, do not repair :)